# Как сделать такой движущий объект с помощью CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3, дизайн, design

Привет всем!

Пытаюсь реализовать такие-же облачка как на этом сайте в первом блоке https://www.xeovo.com

Украсть не получилось, по этому пытаюсь найти статью примерную где описывают как сделать такое.

Самое интересное что даже на мобильных всё нормально отображает, старые наброски не буду показывать ибо там ужас.
Буду очень признателен если поможете.

Answer (score 2):

css [animation @keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Поддержка браузерами - [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.clouds img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.clouds img.cloud1 {
  top: 30px;
  animation: cloud1 45s linear 1s infinite;
  opacity: 0
}
@keyframes cloud1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 0
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 70px
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 1000px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 1088px
  }
}
.clouds img.cloud2 {
  top: 25px;
  animation: cloud2 35s linear 6s infinite;
  opacity: 0
}
@keyframes cloud2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 0
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 70px
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 1000px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 1088px
  }
}
.clouds img.cloud3 {
  top: 115px;
  animation: cloud3 30s linear 11s infinite;
  opacity: 0
}
@keyframes cloud3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 0
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 70px
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 1000px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 1088px
  }
}
.clouds img.cloud4 {
  top: 70px;
  animation: cloud4 55s linear 16s infinite;
  opacity: 0
}
@keyframes cloud4 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 0
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 70px
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 1000px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 1088px
  }
}
.clouds img.cloud5 {
  top: 200px;
  animation: cloud5 25s linear 20s infinite;
  opacity: 0
}
@keyframes cloud5 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 0
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 70px
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 1000px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 1088px
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="clouds">
    <img src="https://www.xeovo.com/img/clouds/cloud-1.png" alt="Cloud" class="cloud1">
    <img src="https://www.xeovo.com/img/clouds/cloud-2.png" alt="Cloud" class="cloud2">
    <img src="https://www.xeovo.com/img/clouds/cloud-3.png" alt="Cloud" class="cloud3">
    <img src="https://www.xeovo.com/img/clouds/cloud-4.png" alt="Cloud" class="cloud4">
    <img src="https://www.xeovo.com/img/clouds/cloud-5.png" alt="Cloud" class="cloud5">
  </div>
</section>
```